# How to repeatedly listen to serial port DataReceived event for timeout no buffer received?

Tags: c#, serial-port, manualresetevent

I have a serial port connection to weighing indicator(display) that connecting to the scale.

[image: Connection diagram]

The device B has 3 state:

1. No Power(Plug off)
2. Power On(Plug on but not power up)
3. Display Ready(after press power up)

On any state, I can connect to serial port but I can only get *DataReceived* event when display ready state (#3). If on certain timeout no value from *DataReceived*, I need to trigger the screen to alert the user that device is not on ready state. When user press Power On and after the display is ready, then I can revoke the trigger so the screen can continue when *DataReceived* arrived.

I have try using ManualResetEvent based from what I found:

```
ManualResetEvent DataReceivedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        // All the port initialization
        _serialPort.Open();
        TimeSpan waitTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
        bool noData = DataReceivedEvent.WaitOne(waitTime);
}
private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
{
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        DataReceivedEvent.Set();
}
```

The MRE seems promising since I can wait, Set the event so I know the data is received, and return false when WaitOne not Set but it freezing my UI and it just run one time after serial port is open.

Is it possible to put ManualResetEvent under thread to keep loop and wait without freezing UI? I try to search for it but I cannot find it.

Comment: It's better to use an interval timer instead of an event. If you record the last reception time each time you receive serial data and compare the current time obtained when the timer process is called with the recorded last reception time, the length of the period during which no data is received Can be calculated.

Comment: @kunif Yes, I have thought about this earlier regarding time difference. I just thought if there is another way, professional way, recommended way to do it.

Comment: Neither the .NET serial port class nor Win32's native COM port API has such functionality directly. Perhaps the ReadFile of Win32's native COM port API can be detected by terminating with a data-to-data timeout error. Otherwise, programmers usually need to monitor non-communication time using another mechanism, such as an interval timer.

Answer (score 0):

Based from @kunif suggestion, I have come to use `DateTime` as a benchmark to see if the device and display is disconnected. The connection status return accordingly on device turn off, display power up and display ready.

```cs
private DateTime LastBufferTime;
private bool Running { get; set; } = true;
private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Running = true;
    LastBufferTime = DateTime.Now;
    _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived;
    _serialPort.Open();
    Task.Run(() => ThreadTimer());
}
private async void ThreadTimer()
{
    while (Running)
    {
        if ((DateTime.Now - LastBufferTime).TotalSeconds > 5)
        {
           // No response from DataReceived
        }
        else
        {
           // Response from DataReceived
        }
    }
}
private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    LastBufferTime = DateTime.Now;
}
private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_serialPort != null)
    {
        if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            _serialPort.Close();
        }
        _serialPort.DataReceived -= SerialPortOnDataReceived;
        _serialPort.Dispose();
        Running = false;
    }
}
```